# Can you remove a special ship part and keep it for later?

Tags: eclipse

With *special* I mean ship parts which you get as a reward, not the ones you have researched.

So what do you do to the *special* ship parts when you remove them (to make space for other ones)? Do you remove them from the game or do you keep them for re-installation later?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Page 7 of the official rulebook states in relation to ***Ancient Ship Parts*** (which are the special type of parts you are referring to):

> you may place this part in any of your Ships (returning an exist­ing part 
>   if needed); you may also keep the part next to your
>   board and place it later with the Upgrade action; if you later want to
>   replace an Ancient Ship Part, it is discarded.

So to answer your question they are discarded.

Source: [[Official English Rulebook](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5496950/Eclipse-rules/Eclipse_rules_EN_compr.pdf)]